# JPA with self join accessing both alias records

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
   EMP_Name    EMP_Loc EMP_Dept    EMP_Sal Emp_type emp_d
    Arjun       Hyd     Comp        1000    Manager  1
    Ramesh      Hyd     Comp        500     Interim  2
    Ragav       Hyd     Comp        300     Interim  3
    Rajesh      Hyd     Comp        200     Interim  4

select  a.emp_dept ,a.emp_id,b.emp_id, a.emp_loc ,b.emp_dept
     from  
     (select sum(emp_sal) as sett,emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Interim'
                   group by emp_loc,emp_dept
                  ) a
                  inner join 
                  (select emp_sal ,emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Manager'
                  ) b 
     on a.sett=b.emp_sal and a.emp_loc=b.emp_loc and a.emp_dept=b.emp_dept;
```

Employee is @Entity Object and @Id id emp_id ,How to implement this with jpa named query
i have tried this  but its returning only 1 set of records that is from employee alias a

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(strQuery,Employee.class);

Also i tried using @SqlResultSetMapping still same result.

Is it possible with JPA or better to go for Spring JDBC?

update : i have tried with composite key but still same result

Answer (score 0):

i can able to solve this problem by making employee alias b id as @Id